# MySQL won't add foreign key more than one foreign key to same table

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, navicat

I'm having troubles with Navicat on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I'm trying to execute the script, and it brokes on last table saying that can't add foreign key constraint, here is my script, does anyone know am I wrong somewhere?

Thanks in advice

Here is my SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE `SMER` (
    `Ssmer` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Nazivs` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Ssmer`)
    );

CREATE TABLE `Nastavnici` (
    `Snast` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Imen` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Snast`)
    );

CREATE TABLE `PREDMETI` (
    `SPRED` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `NAZIVP` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`SPRED`)
    );

CREATE TABLE `Studenti` (
    `Indeks` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Upisan` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Imes` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `Mesto` VARCHAR(255),
    `Datr` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `Ssmer` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Indeks`, `Upisan`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Studenti_Ssmer` FOREIGN KEY (`Ssmer`) REFERENCES `SMER` (`Ssmer`)
    );  

CREATE TABLE `USLOVNI` (
    `Spred` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `UslPredmet` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Spred`, `UslPredmet`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Uslovni_Spred` FOREIGN KEY (`Spred`) REFERENCES `PREDMETI` (`SPRED`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Uslovni_UslPredmet` FOREIGN KEY (`UslPredmet`) REFERENCES `PREDMETI` (`SPRED`)
    );

CREATE TABLE `Planst` (
    `Ssmer` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Spred` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Semestar` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Ssmer`, `Spred`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Planst_Ssmer` FOREIGN KEY (`Ssmer`) REFERENCES `SMER` (`Ssmer`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Planst_Spred` FOREIGN KEY (`Spred`) REFERENCES `PREDMETI` (`SPRED`)
    );

CREATE TABLE `Angazovanje` (
    `Snast` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Spred` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Ssmer` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Snast`, `Spred`, `Ssmer`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Angazovanje_Snast` FOREIGN KEY (`Snast`) REFERENCES `Nastavnici` (`Snast`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Angazovanje_Spred` FOREIGN KEY (`Spred`) REFERENCES `PREDMETI` (`SPRED`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Angazovanje_Ssmer` FOREIGN KEY (`Ssmer`) REFERENCES `SMER` (`Ssmer`)
    );

CREATE TABLE `Prijave` (
    `Spred` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Indeks` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Upisan` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Snast` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `Datump` DATETIME DEFAULT NOW(),
    `Ocena` INT(2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Spred`, `Indeks`, `Upisan`, `Datump`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Prijave_Spred` FOREIGN KEY (`Spred`) REFERENCES `PREDMETI` (`SPRED`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Prijave_Indeks` FOREIGN KEY (`Indeks`) REFERENCES `Studenti` (`Indeks`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Prijave_Upisan` FOREIGN KEY (`Upisan`) REFERENCES `Studenti` (`Upisan`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_Prijave_Snast` FOREIGN KEY (`Snast`) REFERENCES `Nastavnici` (`Snast`)
    );
```

Here is the error message:

```
     [Err] 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: Paste the exact error message also ?

Comment: Im not sure, but it could be that two different foreign keys to one and the same table `Studenti` is not allowed (at least not in all MySQL versions). Do you still get the same error if you remove one of the constraints? FOr example try to remove the row `CONSTRAINT FK_Prijave_Upisan FOREIGN KEY (Upisan) REFERENCES Studenti (Upisan),` and let us know if error still exists...

Comment: When I remove that constraint, it works as well

Comment: (Navicat is irrelevant. The OS of your MySQL server might be relevant because of table name case sensitivity.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two FKs from your `Prijave` table pointing to your `Studenti` table. MySQL doesn't play nicely with that.

Try this

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_Prijave_Indeks` FOREIGN KEY (`Indeks`, `Upisan`)
                               REFERENCES `Studenti` (`Indeks`, `Upisan`),
```

in place of this.

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_Prijave_Indeks` FOREIGN KEY (`Indeks`) REFERENCES `Studenti` (`Indeks`), /* wrong !*/
CONSTRAINT `FK_Prijave_Upisan` FOREIGN KEY (`Upisan`) REFERENCES `Studenti` (`Upisan`),
```

Comment: That's it. I didn't know that must be done in that way.